# Moved ESP32 project from C-drive to H-drive. Now Cmake won't compile

Tags: cmake, directory, esp32, esp-idf

Moved ESP32 project from C-drive to H-drive and now it won't compile. I tried deleting build folder and using `idf.py fullclean` before moving the project folder as suggested, but it didn't solve my problem.

CMakeError.log contains the following information:

> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
> Change Dir:
> //usersrv/users/user/esp_projects/guide/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build
> Command(s):C:/esp/tools/.espressif/tools/ninja/1.10.0/ninja.exe
> cmTC_637a9 && [1/2] Building C object
> CMakeFiles/cmTC_637a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_637a9
>
> FAILED: cmTC_637a9
>
> cmd.exe /C "cd . &&
> C:\esp\tools.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2020r3-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
> -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address CMakeFiles/cmTC_637a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_637a9 && cd ."
>
> '\usersrv\users\user\esp_projects\guide\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp'
>
> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>
> UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
>
> xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: error:
> CMakeFiles/cmTC_637a9.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj: No such file or
> directory xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: it looks like ```idf.py clean``` does not work in such case. In my case manual deletion of build folder fixed such issue

Comment: How about posting that as the answer and claiming the honour?

Comment: it looks like it is somehow related to network mapped drives - like cmake is trying to use network path instead of "local" path which normally starts with drive letter. I wonder whether [mounting remote shared folder into local sub-folder of C: drive](https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-do-i-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder) would help... - to break cmake's weird transformation of path from drive letter based one into remote based path...

Answer (score 3):

You need to

- either **delete build folder** manually
- or invoke `idf.py fullclean`.

here is excerpt from official documentation:

> idf.py clean will “clean” the project by deleting build output files
> from the build directory, forcing a “full rebuild” the next time the
> project is built. Cleaning doesn’t delete CMake configuration output
> and some other files.
>
> idf.py fullclean will delete the entire “build” directory contents.
> This includes all CMake configuration output. The next time the
> project is built, CMake will configure it from scratch. Note that this
> option recursively deletes all files in the build directory, so use
> with care. Project configuration is not deleted.

So if you copy project folder without deleting build folder it still contains make files with references to the old folder thus making build process to fail.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information instead of making a new post.

Comment: Roger. New information added to this post. Other post deleted.